# WiX Heat.exe generates different output after VS2008 -> VS2015 upgrade

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2008, wix, heat

We execute the following command line with heat (3.0.5210.0):

```
heat.exe -srd -suid file OurLib.dll -out bin_OurLib.tmp
```

OurLib.dll is a VC++ 2008 dll file, it's a COM component.

Output (bin_OurLib.tmp)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
        <Fragment>
            <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
                <Component Id="OurLib.dll" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
                    <File Id="OurLib.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\OurLib.dll">
                        <Class Id="{B1AB297C-1BC6-65E1-A7C1-A1833DFAED6A}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="OurProduct.OurLib">
                            <ProgId Id="OurProduct.OurLib" Description="OurProduct.OurLib" />
                        </Class>
                    </File>
                </Component>
            </DirectoryRef>
        </Fragment>
    </Wix>
```

This works fine.
Now we updated the VS to 2015, and compiled OurLib with it.
Running the same heat command now results in different output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
        <Fragment>
            <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
                <Component Id="OurLib.dll" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
                    <Class Id="{B1AB297C-1BC6-65E1-A7C1-A1833DFAED6A}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="OurProduct.OurLib">
                        <ProgId Id="OurProduct.OurLib" Description="OurProduct.OurLib" />
                    </Class>
                    <File Id="OurLib.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\OurLib.dll" />
                    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{B1AB297C-1BC6-65E1-A7C1-A1833DFAED6A}\InProcServer32" Value="&quot;[#OurLib.dll]&quot;" Type="string" Action="write" />
                </Component>
            </DirectoryRef>
        </Fragment>
    </Wix>
```

And when wix is linking, it gives error:

error LGHT0130 : The primary key 'reg51A1FC16367511AF81E9B18CA009A1C6' is duplicated in table 'Registry'.  Please remove one of the entries or rename a part of the primary key to avoid the collision.

Checking the wixobj file, reg51A1FC16367511AF81E9B18CA009A1C6 is related to line
`<Class Id="{B1AB297C-1BC6-65E1-A7C1-A1833DFAED6A}...."` and `<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{B1AB....` - obviously.

Anwyay, this is obviously due to the generated wix output files are different.
Why is that if compiling a dll with a newer C++ compiler will cause WIX HEAT to generate different output, while running the same options, etc.

And how can I have back the same "old" output, which we need.

Tried with -scom and -sreg, none of them gave back the "old" output.

Answer (score 1):

Well primary key duplicated means you've got that same RegistryValue in two different places in your wix source code somehow.

Or maybe the newer DLL is self-registering differently? It's putting the InProcServer32 value in quotes. I don't think that's normal.

Or have you checked that your 2008 and 2015 DLL source and project files are identical? The VS project upgrade process changes things...

Comment: `1)` Yes, _duplicated keys_ are from line 6 + 10 (in second xml)..........`2)` _DLL self-registering_ might be different with the new VC++ compiler, that should be checked, however that does not look an easy task........`3)` yes, source is the same, project file is not used, we compile from command line (cl.exe / link.exe)

Comment: 2) I would at least compare HKCR\CLSID\{B1AB297C-1BC6-65E1-A7C1-A1833DFAED6A}\InProcServer32 values. Is one quoted and the other not?

Comment: I checked, and both 2008 and 2015 compiled DLL self-registering stores the same keys + values in registry. Except one difference in value: exactly that key you said: vs2008 stores as short-path format (no quotes), vs2015 stores as long path format, **in quotes**. But I don't think this could be the reason of that significant difference in the generated .wxs files. But I might be wrong.

Comment: I tested, manually updated that vs2015 registered registry value to short path format without quotes (just as vs2008 registers it) - heat generates the same output. I downloaded the latest 3.11.xx heat (we use an old version, 3.0.xx), but that does not run for some reason on my system with vs2015 built dll, fails with `heat.exe : error HEAT0001 : Illegal characters in path.`. Even with short-path in registry, same error. I will try to figure out why is this, and then maybe try to debug (as it has source-code), why it generates different output.

Comment: Does your COM dll use ATL and a .rgs file?

Comment: Thanks, that looks something to consider. It seems, which component has .rgs file, its wxs file is created OK. My question is about 1 dll (without rgs file), but in fact we have dozens. I should still compare to be sure, but it looks like if there is an rgs file, wxs is created properly. Also, we have .net controls, with COM visible flag, for those, after new VS build, heat generates basically empty wxs...but that is going to be my next question.

Comment: Ok, it seems if the DLL uses "old style low level" COM (MFC OLE macros, etc), then we have the issue with HEAT + VS2015. If we use "new" style, ATL, .rgs file, etc, then even if compiled with VC++2015, HEAT can create proper wxs.

Comment: A side note for you comment _**It's putting the InProcServer32 value in quotes. I don't think that's normal.**_: I debugged the error with the latest version of Heat: `heat.exe : error HEAT0001 : Illegal characters in path.` - this is due to that in "old style COM server", the `DllRegisterServer` calls `COleObjectFactory::UpdateRegistryAll();`, which in VS2015 stores the CLSID registry path as long name, surrounded by quotes (hardcoded in `VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\olereg.cpp`). Problem is Heat.exe cannot handle paths in quotes, thus I have this error. This is MS code, so it supposed to be normal(?)

Comment: So, using latest wix, and "fixing" heat.exe code (its source is available) to support path in quotes, solves the issue.

Comment: Happy you got it working. Might be worth filing a bug at https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues, and even making a pull request so you can give them your fix...

Comment: Thanks the link, I searched, and found the same error: [link](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4250). Although, it is not fixed yet. "_even making a pull request so you can give them your fix..._" - I have never participated in opensource project...don't know how it works, but might be interesting, will consider.

Comment: http://wixtoolset.org/development/ outlines the process, but basically send a message to the wix-devs list asking them how you can contribute your fix. They should be very appreciative of your help...